# Keeping two rows together when sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, sorting

I would like to know how to link specific rows when sorting a table in excel. I have already made the table and in each row contains data for a specific person. Each person has two rows. My boss would like the ability to sort the data but the two rows stay together even if it doesn't follow the sort.

Example
[image: Example]

So if I were to sort by SK in this image, he'd want the person with the most sacks to be at the top but also their second row right beneath even if that second row doesn't have the second most sacks. THEN the next player with the second most snacks followed by their second row regardless of whether their second row doesn't have the 4th most sacks and so on.

Comment: You could do it with helper columns, one each for any data element you might want to sort by. IOW if you wanted to sort by most sacks you'd add a field called [Highest Sack Year for This Player] and `{=MAX(IF($A:$A=$A2,$G:$G)}` entered as array formula (assuming A is names and G is sacks as it appears to be in your example). Then sort by that field.

Comment: Sort by player first, and then by SK

Comment: Create a helper column with merge cells... sort the merge cells??

Answer (score 0):

Excel cannot do that with inbuilt functions - you will need to learn VBA
and write a VBA macro to do that, actually two macros:

The first macro : To pack the two rows into one, by concatenating the
second row's columns to the first and delete the each second row.

Then you can sort the rows as you like.

The second macro will finally unpack the combined rows into two rows each.

This is not an easy solution, but I don't see a better one.